# FullCalendar not showing color of event properly

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

The color of event is not showing properly, i tried it in many ways, including eventSources. I tried to change it even by fixed code, but the result is still the same as in the following picture.

[Picture Of FullCalendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eOwL.png)

The color is taken dynamically from database, here is the result of the request:

```
allDay: false
backgroundColor: "#00ff00"
color: "#00ff00"
editable: false
title: "Administrative Team: Shift A"
start:"2018-01-01T09:00:00"
end: "2018-01-01T17:00:00"
```

Here is the code that i have tried:

```
function GenerateSchedule(Preview) {
        var events = [];

        var JsonParam = ({
            'DateFrom': $("#datefrom").datepicker('getDate'),
            'DateTo': $("#dateto").datepicker('getDate'),
            'Id': $("#Plan_Id option:selected").val(),
            'GenerateSchedule': Preview
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GenerateSchedule", "SchedulerGenerator")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ model: JsonParam }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                Jdata = JSON.parse(result)
                $.each(Jdata, function (i, v) {
                    events.push({
                        title: v.TeamName + ': ' + v.ShiftName,
                        start: v.PlannedDateIn,
                        end: v.PlannedDateOut,
                        allDay: false,
                        editable: false,
                        color: v.ShiftColor,
                        backgroundColor: v.ShiftColor,
                        eventColor: v.ShiftColor,
                    });
                });
                FullCalendar(events);
            },
        });
    };

    function FullCalendar(events) {
        $('#full-calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
        $('#full-calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: new Date(),
            timeFormat: 'h (mm)a',
            header: {
                left: 'prev, next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month, basicWeek, basicDay, agenda'
            },
            events: events,
        });
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not showing properly means what? Is it showing color?

Comment: It is not showing the color from the backgroundColor or eventColor, it must be a bright green on the background, taken from database, but it is showing only that blue color, even if i change it manually it won't change!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i did was in the events color, backgroundColor, and eventColor added ' + "!important" ' because something was overwriting my colors. Thanks for your concern!

Answer (score 0):

Add 'className' with each event.

```
events.push({
title: v.TeamName + ': ' + v.ShiftName,
start: v.PlannedDateIn,
end: v.PlannedDateOut,
className: 'event-class-style-name' });
```

Comment: className doesn't make any difference

Comment: Still the same result, i had the className but removed it!

Comment: This is working fine for me. Check the same inside 'eventRender' callback